# ARC UINavigationController stack not getting deallocated when presented as modal view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, modal-dialog, automatic-ref-counting

First: I ported my App to ARC and everything seemed to work. But now I discovered a problem: I have a UINavigationController that is presented modally with some UIViewControllers on its stack. But when I dismiss the modal view controller, the view controllers from the stack don't seem to be deallocated. Here is what I do:

```
UIViewController* root = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController* navi = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:root];
[self presentModalViewController:navi animated:TRUE];
```

Then from the root I push some more view controllers, but that doesn't really matter. The fact is when I later call

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
```

root doesn't get deallocated. Of course in my code root is a subclass of UIViewController, and I track dealloc and viewDidUnload, but nothing gets called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's inside your navigation controller? It could be that something else (perhaps a view controller inside your navigation controller) is the culprit, which is leading up the chain meaning the navigation controller doesn't get released.

Either way, the code you posted is correct, so if your navigation controller isn't being released after calling `dismissModalViewController` it would suggest that something else still has an active reference to it or one of its dependencies. I know that doesn't answer your question, but you will probably have to hunt around.

Comment: Inside the UINavigationController there is nothing special, it's the standard class. And there are no more references to the UINavigationController or the UIViewcontroller then shown above. I didn't want to post too much unnecessary code. But I'm about to make some experiments on that topic and post my results later...

Comment: Ok, ok, I actually found a strong reference to the ViewController (shame on me). It has been a delegate to another custom class and the delegate was declared as id <ScanManagerDelegate> delegate; which defaults to __strong under ARC. Sorry for that! So to all you people out there using delegates under ARC: Make them weak if the Migration tool doesn't do it for you!

Comment: No need to be sorry - it's useful to know! Something I will have to look out for when I have to migrate a project over.

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't showing actual code, it's hard to tell what is going on with your root view controller.

But, with ARC, if you have a strong pointer to an object, it won't get released. I suspect that you are holding on to this controller after adding it to your navigation controller.

But, without seeing your code, I can't tell.